# 403 Forbidden returned for any Stack Exchange page

Tags: support, status-bydesign, error-message, 403-forbidden

When I try to connect to any Stack Exchange site from work, I notice that it comes up as `403: Forbidden` on Windows. I checked my corporate web filter and SE sites are not on the blacklist. Why can I access SO from any computer *except* the Windows machines at work?

Comment: Can you ping stackoverflow.com (or any other site that's affected) and post the IP that responds? If it's not one of SO's servers, then there's something wrong with the DNS.

Comment: This isn't meta enough.  Belongs on SuperUser!

Comment: Try http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/superuser.com from one of your *down* machines.

Comment: That's a good idea Kyle. Ping seems to respond and has the correct IP for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're on the banned IP list.

Email us via the link at the bottom of every page with your IP.

Comment: OOOOOOOoooooooo

Comment: That explains it. :-)

Comment: ...and resolved!