# 403 while trying to access Stack Overflow

Tags: support, stack-overflow, 403-forbidden

I am not sure why, but when I try to access `www.stackoverflow.com` I get a `403 Access denied` error, as if my IP address is banned.

I connected via my work VPN, just to post this question.

I use Stack Overflow a lot, so I would like for it to work normally. I get a static IP from my ISP, so I can't get get a new one easily. What is going on?

I have tried to connect using FF, IE and Chrome, all with the same effect.

Comment: Connecting through a proxy?

Comment: possible duplicate of [403 Forbidden returned for any Stack Exchange page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8596/403-forbidden-returned-for-any-stack-exchange-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your IP has been banned for anomalous access patterns, most likely -- email team@stackoverflow.com with details.