# What events/policy changes etc. in SO have exogenously manipulated things like views, answers, votes etc.?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, community, community-data

I'm doing some quantitative research on SO and I'm trying to find good "natural" or quasi-experiments that have occurred or will occur in SO.

What I mean by a natural experiment is some policy change, events or even feature of the system that manipulates things like:

1) Views received
2) Answers received
3) Probability that an answer is accepted
4) Up votes / down votes

The changes should manipulate these variables in a manner that's similar to what you would find in a true experiment.

To provide an example, imagine I wanted to see if users asked more questions later if their first question received many answers. You obviously cannot just treat "answers received on first question" as an independent variable---it's almost certainly correlated with the posters characteristics, which will affect both the answers they receive and their future behavior. However, suppose by chance that a posters' question got a 10X increase in views because **X** happened that day, then we could exploit this shock to try to uncover the causal effect of getting more views by comparing them to others with **~X**.

So, to summarize, I'm looking for some ideas on **X**.

Also - it would be helpful if you have an approximate date when the change was implemented or will be implemented.

---

Thanks for your answers - these are great. Too bad I had to pick just one answer. "Gentlemen, you've both worked very hard, and in a way, you're both winners. But in another more accurate way, Barney is the winner."

Comment: I'm looking to do a similar analysis to @john-horton, and these answers are great, but I'm curious whether there's anything more recent than three years ago. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Change:** Order answers with the same vote total randomly rather than based on time.
**Implemented:** circa Aug 2009 (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18067/possible-solution-to-the-vote-ordering-controversy))
**Result:** Theoretically, to level the playing field with respect to time of arrival as a solution to the FGITW problem.

Comment: Thanks - do you know about when this happened? I've been searching but haven't found a good link yet.

Comment: @John -- updated with date.

Answer (score 6):

**Change**: Display accepted answer ratio.
**Result**: A lot of answers being accepted immediately after the policy change, and now some people are unwilling to answer questions from users with a low ratio.

**Change**: Electorate badge for voting on a lot of questions as well as answers.
**Result**: I've heard of at least one user now voting more on questions; I don't know what effect it's had globally though.

Comment: Negative effect: I don't vote on answers *at all* because of that badge

Comment: @Downvoter -- not even downvotes.  Now that's a shame.  ;-)

Comment: Aww, man, I thought everyone had only posted one change per answer. I'd just finished writing up my analysis of the electorate badge when I chanced to scroll up one last time and noticed the second change.

Comment: I definitely increased my voting on questions when the electorate badge came out, and even after receiving it, have kept up the habit.

Comment: "Display accepted answer ration" certainly has increased the amount of complaining, about users who rarely accept answers.

Comment: After the Electorate badge appeared my answer voting stayed pretty much the same, but my question voting (specifically *downvotes*) spiked dramatically. Now that I have the badge, I still downvote off-topic questions more often than I did before, but not as much as I was when the badge first appeared.

Answer (score 4):

**Change**: You are [unable to change your display name more than once per month](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29966/can-we-restrict-the-ability-of-users-to-keep-changing-their-names)
**Result**: I cannot find a suitable display name I'd like to have for a month so I keep the one I had when the change was implemented, also, it made Meta more boring.

Comment: Screw you, pal.

Comment: Yeah, more boring sucks!

Answer (score 1):

**Change:** Low rep users get a "have you considered commenting" popup when they down-vote an answer.
**Implemented:** July 2009 (< 500 rep), modified December 2009 (< 2000 rep) - see the [revision history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/2373/revisions) for Jeff's answer that announced the change.
**Result:** Again theoretically, increase the number of comments that go with down-votes so the poster can know what was wrong with the question or answer and so correct it.